# Solve the recurrence relation $a_n = -a_{n-1} + n^2,\ n \geq 1$, $a_{0}$ = 3

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the recurrence relation $a_n = -a_{n-1} + n^2$ where $n \geq 1$, $a_{0} = 3$.

I have the first few terms of the sequence

$a_1= -2,\quad a_2=6,\quad a_3=3,\quad a_4=13,\quad \dots$

however after this point I am a little lost as to what I should do next, as I cant find a pattern in this sequence and am unsure what the characteristic equation would look like. Would anyone care to give me any hints as to what the next step would be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: What could be improved upon with how I asked this question?

Comment: how did you get $a_1=-2$? should $a_0$ be $-3$?

Comment: There was a typo, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

The alternating character of this sequence suggests dealing with two steps at a time. So let's consider
\begin{align*}a_{n+1}&=-a_{n}+(n+1)^2\\&=-(-a_{n-1}+n^2)+(n+1)^2\\&=a_{n-1}+(n+1)^2-n^2\\&=a_{n-1}+2n+1.\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

---

To finish things up: let's consider even terms first:

\begin{align*}a_{2n}&=a_{2(n-1)}+2(2n)-1\\
&=a_{2(n-2)}+2(2(n-1))-1+2(2n)-1\\
&=\dots\\
&=a_0+4\sum_{k=1}^{n}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}1\\
&=a_0+4\cdot \frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}-n\\
&= 2n^2+n+a_0
\end{align*}
and lastly
$$a_{2n+1}=-a_{2n}+(2n+1)^2=-(2n^2+n+a_0)+(2n+1)^2=2n^2+3n+1-a_0$$

Comment: I believe so. Thanks for the help. Is this a general method for solving recurrence relations that are alternating, such as this one?

Comment: let me know if you get to the result.

Comment: You got it, will do!

Comment: So I have been trying for a couple hours and I am still as lost as I was before. Is there any more guidance you could provide me?

Comment: I've completed the answer. It's a nice problem!

Comment: Ah there it is Nice work! used a computational resource this morning and I got this identity.

$\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{\left(\left(-1\right)^{n}n\left(n+1\right)+6\right)} {2}$